# UPDATE statement where MAX query show error 1093

Tags: mysql, sql-server, xampp

Why this query didn't work

[Sql commandline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h14v8.png)

update gaji set jumlah_gaji='10'
where jumlah_gaji = (select max(jumlah_gaji) from gaji);

Comment: thx for the dupe lookup peanutbutter

Comment: I can't understand that

Comment: Please edit your code in as text. I shouldn't have to type that in myself.

Comment: n MySQL, you can't modify the same table which you use in the SELECT part. Look in to the below link..
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/update.html

For the alternative approach go to the below link:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/45494/mysql-error-1093-cant-specify-target-table-for-update-in-from-clause

Comment: http://hastebin.com/miyehidira.rb

Comment: Woo, thank you very much Drew

Comment: no problem boss. There are many ways to do it. Over and out.